# How to get the time from native android alarm clock application. Is there a chance to get the time from AlarmClock function?

Tags: java, android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
```

I want to get the value set from `AlarmClock.Action_Set_Alarm`
in order to be set text to a text-field in the application.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem with broadcast receiver

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=broadcast+receiver+alarm+